# Placing View over TitleBar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there any way I can place a `ContentView` or `Grid` to cover complete page in Xamarin.Forms?

I need to place it over the `TitleBar` area without hiding the  `TitleBar`.

I tried to achieve the same using `RelativeLayout` but it is not working. I am trying to achieve something similar to a popup/modal.

Sadly I can't use any *Third Party* control in my project or **PushModal** either.

Ideas?

Adding the sample screen.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot/image of how you imagine the result?

Comment: Agree with julipan, can you share a screenshot about your needs, Push an alert above the titleBar like notifcation?

Comment: Added the image. In my parent page the Title bar is there. I need to create this as a popup that cover the titleview

Comment: You can create a custom toolbar then add  `SearchBar` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar

Answer (score 0):

You could set in **Xaml**:

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar = "False"
```

Comment: op do not want to hide the TitleBar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the content whole page and without hiding the title bar, then you need to make the title bar transparant.Follow this tutorial  https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

or

If you are trying to achieve popup, consider using this wonderfull plugin https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: op do not want to use any Third Party control